# Special characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, special-characters, alert, confirm

I have a java script and the code is

```
confirm("You are selecting to start an Associate who is Pending Red (P RD) status. Is this your intent?")
```

[image]

but i get the below alert with some special characters and but if i see the alert code that i have written, there is no special characters but i get this special character when i execute this code.

dont really know what is the issue....

Comment: Did you copy and paste that string from somewhere? That space might not be what you think it is.

Comment: works for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/meo22u3a/. check if you see the same here..

Comment: NO @SterlingArcher, i did not copy this string from anywhere.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Make a fiddle or a runnable snippet that shows the issue please.

Comment: It may be an encoding issue, try replacing all the spaces with `\u0020`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be `\uFEFF` or `\xA0` (BOM and NBSP) make sure you use a space (`\u0020`).